# Background Image opacity in CSS (working in dreamweaver)

Tags: html, css, background-image, dreamweaver, opacity

Working in Dreamweaver, I'm trying to get a background image that is the same on every page. I want it to be set and fill the whole page, have content scroll *not* the picture, and I need the picture to be a bit transparent, so the text will be easier to read. I have NO idea how to do opacity other than that this is what I have in my Style.css class.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:
         url(/CuzbZDV%5B1%5D.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: The image is a JPEG, it is opaque as is.

Comment: you're right, I worded this incorrectly. I want it to be more transparent but changing the opacity. In the past I have just used thisline of code:



    img {
        opacity: 0.45;
        filter: alpha(opacity=45); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
body:before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  content: " ";
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8, I believe... */
}
```